# VBA: For/if/ElseIf

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, if-statement

I got a problem concerning VBA in Excel.
I have an userform, and if the user enters a entry that isnt already in the row, I want it to be added.

```
Range("D1:D1").Select

For i = 1 To 3000

  Zelle = "D" & i
  Range(Zelle).Select
  Wert = ActiveCell

  If Wert = "" Then
   Cells(Wert + 1, 4) = TB_prov
   Exit For
  ElseIf Wert = TB_prov Then
   Exit For
   Else
    Next i

End If
Exit For
```

I took an old code from the internet which helped me for a similar problem but I can't make it work here.

My intention was that the For-loop changes the active cell,
and the if/elseif conditions check every cell.
If the new entry is already existing, it stops. If the cell is empty, it puts the name is.

But it doenst work, but why?
Thanks for help

Comment: What doesn't work?

Comment: Is TB_prov a string and Wert a Long?

Comment: Because  If Wert = ""  is expecting a string but you then try  Cells(Wert + 1, 4)  which expects a numeric datatype

Comment: TB_prov is a textbox in the userform

Comment: I don't want to add a new answer because Jeeped's answer is a much better solution than simply fixing the code, but I think it probably deserves to be mentioned that the reason the original code fails is because the Next i, End If and Exit For at the end of the original code are out of order

Answer (score 1):

Look for a match down column D. Add TB_prov if not found. No need to loop through all the values.

```
with activesheet
    if iserror(application.match(TB_prov, .columns("D"), 0)) then
        .cells(.rows.count, "D").end(xlup).offset(1, 0) = TB_prov
    end if
end with
```